# Editor role can only manage right region of page, no other region allowed

Tags: 7, blocks, users, theming

In drupal 7, I have a page that has 3 regions: header, right sidebar and footer.   I also have 2 user roles: Admin and Editor.   An admin should be able to create content, edit content, publish content, and manage blocks in all three regions.  An editor should be able to create content, edit content, NOT publish content and only manage blocks in the right sidebar of pages he created and edited.

I used the revisioning module to prevent editors from publishing content.  So now Admin's must review editor changes before publishing.  **However, how do I restrict and editor's ability to managing ONLY the right sidebar of ONLY the pages he created/editted?**